# Grafana create groups with hosts

Tags: grafana

I am monitoring few servers instead of me creating a new dashboard, I would like to create a group (or subgroup) in a template. Is that possible to do with Grafana?

Comment: Yes, it's possible: http://docs.grafana.org/reference/templating/

Comment: I see, do I do this with tagging?

Comment: No, you're doing it with templating as described in the link I posted. Tags are used only for organizing your dashboard, not for parametrization. You need to click the gear symbol on the top bar (`Manage dashboard`) and select `Templating`.

Comment: I see. I am using telegraf to collect data. So, I think I would need to use apps as a grouper. Let me play around with it